# Python: How to add text on plot 2D mesh "TypeError: 'str' object is not a mapping"

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am looking for adding node number on the plot as the figure attached. unfortunately, I started with the following code, however it generates the following er[image]ror "TypeError: 'str' object is not a mapping", given the following information, coordinates of each node, what nodes belong to each element, and the value each node has.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
el_con=np.array([[0,3,4,1],[1,4,5,2]])
coord=np.array([[0,0,0],[0,0,.0625],[0,0,.1250],[25,0,0],[25,0,0.0625],[25,0,.1250]])

for i in range (len(el_con)):
       el_con_n=el_con[i,:]
       X = coord[el_con[i,:],0].reshape((-1, 1))
       Y = coord[el_con[i,:],1].reshape((-1, 1))
       Z = coord[el_con[i,:],2].reshape((-1, 1))
       plt.fill(X, Z, edgecolor='black', fill=False)
       for j in range (2):
           x=el_con[i][j]
           plt.text(X[j],Y[j],Z[j],str(x))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be (attempting to) add text using the Z index/coordinate when the `plt.text()` method only takes two coordinates (x and y) as parameters. [The specification for plt.text()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html) is as follows:

```py
matplotlib.pyplot.text(x: float, y: float, s: str, fontdict=None, **kwargs)
```

where `x` and `y` are the X and Y coordinates and `s` is the Str containing the text you wish to add to the image.

In other words, remove the 3rd parameter which should be a string and not a coordinate.

```py
plt.text(X[j], Y[j], str(x))
```

Your complete code should look like this, now:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
el_con = np.array([[0, 3, 4, 1], [1, 4, 5, 2]])
coord = np.array([
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, .0625],
    [0, 0, .1250],
    [25, 0, 0],
    [25, 0, .0625],
    [25, 0, .1250],
    ])

for i in range(len(el_con)):
    el_con_n = el_con[i]  # Note: second index is redundant. Use `el_con[i]` instead.
    X = coord[el_con_n, 0].reshape((-1, 1))
    Y = coord[el_con_n, 1].reshape((-1, 1))
    Z = coord[el_con_n, 2].reshape((-1, 1))
    plt.fill(X, Z, edgecolor='black', fill=False)
    for j in range(2):
        x = el_con[i][j]
        plt.text(X[j], Y[j], str(x))
plt.show()
```

Note that you might have to replace the `Y[j]` with `Z[j]` while still only keeping two coordinates on the `plt.text(x, y, s)` line, because it looks like `Z` may actually be your `y` coordinate.

Comment: Thank you so much , it works now, 
I accepted your answer, however, I kindly ask you if you could tell me/suggest me a way to put a larger font for the text as it's very small and possibility to put them a way a bit from the lines, 

Thank you again

Comment: No problem. I would encourage you to read the documentation that I linked regarding `matplotlib.pyplot.text`. The documentation clearly explains how to change the font size. That being said, here is how you can adjust the font size: `plt.text(X[j], Y[j], str(x), fontsize=18)`. As for placing the text "a bit from the lines", you can simply add or subtract from the `x` and `y` values. For example, you can try this: `plt.text(X[j] + 10, Y[j] - 10, str(x), fontsize=16)`, which should place the text above and to the right (by 10 pixels) of where it previously was.